# How do I send commands from PHP script to Terminal running a Python interpreter?

Tags: php, python, shell, interpreter, maya

I want to access the Terminal from a PHP script to open a standalone version of Maya and then run a Python script in Maya from the Terminal.

I've been able to send commands to the Terminal from my PHP script using the `exec()` function. For example, I've been able to open Maya with an .OBJ file using the following code.

```
//Open Maya with .OBJ
$cmd='open -a /Applications/Autodesk/maya2015/maya.app /Applications/AMPPS/www/webGL/upload/Character.obj';
exec($cmd);
```

I then found that I could open a Maya Python interpreter in the Terminal using this directory:
**/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy**

When this directory is executed in the Terminal, it runs the Maya Python interpreter. When the interpreter is running it seems that I am no longer able to send commands (which is now Python code) to the Terminal from my PHP script.

Am I going down the right path with using the `exec()` function to carry out what I want to do? Or does this function simply execute single commands and not multiple commands consecutively in the same Terminal? Do I need to use a different function that sends commands to a specific shell so that all the commands are being executed in the same Terminal?

Here is the code that I have been trying to send to the Terminal to run the Maya Python interpreter and then import the Maya standalone library and initialise it.

```
//Open Maya interpreter
$cmd2="/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy";
//Import standalone and initialise
$cmd3="import maya.standalone; maya.standalone.initialize( name='python' )"

//Execute commands
shell_exec($cmd2);
shell_exec($cmd3);
```

Comment: use [popen()](http://php.net/popen), which lets you have a bi-directional conversation with an external process.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem... are you _sure_ you _need_ to call python from php? At the very least, why not write a python script to be interpreted rather than opening up python and feeding it input in interactive mode?

Comment: @ChrisSprague yes actually that would be the ideal method. I have a Python script already written, how would I then have this script interpreted in Maya? A command needs to be called from the PHP script as it resides on the server and is executed by an AJAX request from my webpage.

Comment: @skelto can't say I know maya, but if I had to take a gander, it would be run as something like `mayapy /path/to/script.py`. Make sure `mayapy` is added to your `$PATH` -- i.e. add the maya `/bin` to your path

Comment: @ChrisSprague ok I'll try this, thanks for the help!

Comment: @skelto yeah, hope it works out. I would try just running `mayapy` from the terminal to see if it is being picked up in your path; if not, here's [how to add to PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path).

Comment: @ChrisSprague just to be clear, if this is my path to the Maya Python interpreter - `/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy` and this is the path to the Python script that I want to run in Maya - `/Users/Gal/Desktop/Mark's Humane Files/Final Python Files/CreateSkinnedCharacter.py`, then what what would the command sent to the Terminal look like?

Comment: @skelto I'd say `/path/to/interp /path/to/script.py`, but I don't know if that's how the Maya interpreter works, just a usual convention of interpreters (ruby, python, bash, php, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to code separate with mayapy, you can run script directly with mayapy

**test.py**

```
import os
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()
import maya.cmds as cmds
print dir(cmds)
```

You can simply call this script like this

```
mayapy /your/path/test.py
```

In your case

```
$cmd2="/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/bin/mayapy /your/path/test.py";
shell_exec($cmd2);
```